# How to add a new search type?

Tags: magento-1.9, catalogsearch, search-type

I want to add a new search type option in Magento admin configurations section. Please find the attached image for more clarification.

[image]

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

The available types are hard coded in a few places. To add a new type you will have to rewrite these methods:

- Rewrite `Mage_Adminhtml_Model_System_Config_Source_Catalog_Search_Type::toOptionArray()` to add a new type to the dropdown
- Rewrite `Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext::prepareResult()` to return a different resource if `$searchType` is your new type.

*Disclaimer: I never did that and don't know if it will solve your actual problem (whatever you try to do)*

Answer (score 1):

This section is responsible for the option:

```
<search_type translate="label">
    <label>Search Type</label>
    <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
    <backend_model>adminhtml/system_config_backend_catalog_search_type</backend_model>
    <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_catalog_search_type</source_model>
    <sort_order>20</sort_order>
    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
</search_type>
```

If you want to add there your own value, you should extend the model `adminhtml/system_config_source_catalog_search_type`

If you are developing your own search module, then it will be better to rewrite this option to your modules’ configuration and give the priority to it.